# Why Azure publish throw CreateTableIfNotExist error?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am trying to learn how to deploy and use Orleans in Azure. I cloned AzureWebSample from github. I followed the instructions mentioned at http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Samples-Overview/Azure-Web-Sample . When I tried to publish I am getting following error.

1:28:51 AM - Instance 0 of role OrleansAzureSilos is busy
    Details: Recovering role... Unhandled Exception:

Orleans.Runtime.OrleansException, Details: Exception: Failed to create OrleansSiloInstanceManager. This means CreateTableIfNotExist for silo instance table has failed with 
Exc level 0: System.AggregateException:

I couldn't find any help on the documentation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to re-deploy by creating a new web application. Maybe it was some fault in the process and second attempt will be successful. Optionally, you can try deploying a site via Publish wizard, uploading packages and FTP using Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried re-deploying and it did not work. But I am curious about why would the table creation fail.